# Передать управление и параметры сервлету из JSP+JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jstl

Пытаюсь делать приложение по модели MVC используя Servlet+JSP+Jstl
Работа приложения начинается с сервлета, из которого запускается 
JSP

```
requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/EditRecord.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

На странице JSP есть поля ввода/редактирования данных и поля с кнопочкой справа смысл которой в том что бы нажав на эту кнопочку, получить список значений из БД, выбрать одно из них и ввести в поле ввода на форме JSP.(у кнопочки вижу только свойство onclick)
Насколько я понимаю для этого надо по нажатию этой кнопки снова запустить сервлет, выполнить обращения к БД, открыть страницу или окно для выбора значения и вставить его в поле ввода страницы JSP
Вопросы:
Правильный ли ход мыслей?
Не могу разобраться как из JSP запустить сервлет и передать параметры с страницы JSP в сервлет. Если можно помогите примером.

Comment: Выполнить запрос, и все будет хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете на странице jsp создать такую форму, например:

```
<form action="/getvalues" method="get">
<input type="text" name="message"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

в сервлете получить то, что пришло из формы:

```
@WebServlet(name = "GetValues", urlPatterns = "/getvalues")
public class GetValuesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{
        String message = request.getParameter("message");
         //получаете значения из базы, отправляете в нужную jsp.
    }
}
```

Можно также отправить значения в сервлет постредством JavaScript через ajax запрос. При этом не нужно перезагружать страницу полностью. Я приведу пример с Jquery:

js:

```
var message = $('#inputValue').text();
$.ajax({
            url: "/getvalues",
            type: "get",
            data: (message: message),
            dataType: "html",
            success: addValues,
            error: err

        });
function addValues(data){
}

function err(){
}
```

html:

```
<input type='text' id='inputValue'/>
```